# Await / async locking up UI

Tags: c#, async-await

I am currently having issies with the await / asyn methods, i'm trying to import a .txt file of URLs but the UI is still locking up.

**Code**

```
public async void DoImport(string[] files)
{
    ListViewItem lv = null;
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        lv = new ListViewItem(file);
        listViewSites.Items.Add(lv);
        lv.SubItems.Add("...");
        lv.SubItems.Add("...");
    }
}

public async Task ImportTheSitesToUse(string inputFileIncludingFullPath)
{
    try
    {
        string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(inputFileIncludingFullPath);
        await Task.Run(() => DoImport(files));

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helpers.DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
    }
}

private async void BtnImportSitesList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Select your .txt list of URLs ...";
        ofd.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        BtnImportSitesList.Enabled = false;
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            await ImportTheSitesToUse(ofd.FileName.ToString());
        }
        BtnImportSitesList.Enabled = true;
        Helpers.ReturnMessage("Successfully imported [ x ] links.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helpers.DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
    }
}
```

I don't see any obvious issues with the code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your first method 'doimport' is synchronous - it doesn't have 'await'

Comment: `File` has an async version of `ReadAllLines`.  You could await that as well.  [ReadAllLinesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllinesasync?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @Igor DoImport is synchronous so why is it marked as `async void`?

Comment: @RyanWilson That fixes nothing.  It just makes it more obvious what is wrong with the method.  It makes no sense for that method to always return a completed task in the first place.

Comment: @RyanWilson It doesn't change the behavior in any way.  It's still a synchronous method.  You've just made it explicit that it's a synchronous method.

Comment: You are running `DoImport` on a background thread (that's what `Task.Run` does). I'm assuming that `listViewSites` is on your UI. Updating the UI from a background thread always breaks something

Comment: @RyanWilson Calling an async void method from `Task.Run` doesn't deadlock.  If the method were *actually* asynchronous then it'd continue without the operation having finished (which may result in a bug) but it won't cause a deadlock.  Since the method *isn't* asynchronous, it doesn't even have that problem.

Comment: @RyanWilson "Try awaiting it like the OP is doing and see what happens with an async void" Take your own advice and see for yourself that that won't cause a deadlock.

Comment: Don't crossthreading UI components in `DoImport` which accesses `listViewSites.Items.Add`

Comment: Don't use `string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(inputFileIncludingFullPath);` because it reads all lines instead of streaming it. This blocks the UI thread.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I didn't get suspended. I removed my comments as they were wrong and I didn't want to leave erroneous content

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of common issues in the code:

`public async void DoImport(string[] files)`

This method is marked as `async`, but it doesn't use `await`, which makes the method run synchronously. If you look at the Errors window, you will see a warning that complains about that method. Make it `public void`, that's enough.

Let's break down `ImportTheSitesToUse` now. It basically does two things:

1. Read all lines in a file, and
2. Requests a thread pool thread to call `DoImport`

If we keep in mind that with `async`/`await`, the control is returned to the caller on an `await` call, the issue becomes obvious when the biggest part of the work is executed synchronously.
The second issue is that there is no reason to call `DoImport` from a thread pool thread, since it is an inexpensive method, and it also requires to be run on the UI thread (due to the UI object that is being altered).

That said, `ImportTheSitesToUse` should then have the opposite structure:

1. Read all lines in a file asynchronously, and
2. Call `DoImport`

Putting it all together:

```
public void DoImport(string[] files)
{
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem(file);
        listViewSites.Items.Add(lv);
        lv.SubItems.Add("...");
        lv.SubItems.Add("...");
    }
}

public async Task ImportTheSitesToUse(string inputFileIncludingFullPath)
{
    try
    {
        string[] files = await Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllLines(inputFileIncludingFullPath));
        DoImport(files);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Helpers.DebugLogging("[" + DateTime.Now + "]-[" + ex.ToString() + "]");
    }
}
```